Does XeTeX 3.141592653 from TeX Live 2024 support variable fonts (specifically, NotoSansMonoCJKSC-VF.otf)?
I have downloaded these two fonts:

NotoSansMonoCJKSC-VF.otf (permalink to file in the official Github repository)
NotoSansMonoCJKsc-Regular.otf (permalink to file in the official Github repository)

I run fc-cache -f -v, so fc-list is aware of those fonts.
fc-list | grep '\.fonts' | grep 'NotoSansMonoCJKsc'

/home/rodrigo/.fonts/NotoSansMonoCJKsc-VF.otf: Noto Sans Mono CJK SC:style=Medium
/home/rodrigo/.fonts/NotoSansMonoCJKsc-Regular.otf: Noto Sans Mono CJK SC:style=Regular
/home/rodrigo/.fonts/NotoSansMonoCJKsc-VF.otf: Noto Sans Mono CJK SC
/home/rodrigo/.fonts/NotoSansMonoCJKsc-VF.otf: Noto Sans Mono CJK SC:style=Bold
/home/rodrigo/.fonts/NotoSansMonoCJKsc-VF.otf: Noto Sans Mono CJK SC:style=Regular

When using NotoSansMonoCJKsc-Regular.otf, the document compiles without problems.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xeCJK}

\setCJKmainfont[
  Path = {\string~/.fonts/},
  Extension = .otf
]{NotoSansMonoCJKsc-Regular}

\begin{document}
  你好！
\end{document}

xelatex /tmp/main.tex

This is XeTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-0.999996 (TeX Live 2024) (preloaded format=xelatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(/tmp/main.tex
LaTeX2e <2023-11-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2024-03-14>
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2023/05/17 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xecjk/xeCJK.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-xetex.def))
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ctex/ctexhook.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xtemplate/xtemplate.st
y
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xtemplate/xtemplate-20
23-10-10.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec-xetex.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.cfg)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xecjk/xeCJK.cfg)) (./main.aux)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd) [1] (./main.aux) 
)
Output written on main.pdf (1 page).
Transcript written on main.log.

However, when I use NotoSansMonoCJKSC-VF.otf. The message file main.pdf may not be valid. along with some other errors are shown.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xeCJK}

\setCJKmainfont[
  Path = {\string~/.fonts/},
  Extension = .otf
]{NotoSansMonoCJKsc-VF}

\begin{document}
  你好！
\end{document}

xelatex /tmp/main.tex

This is XeTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-0.999996 (TeX Live 2024) (preloaded format=xelatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(/tmp/main.tex
LaTeX2e <2023-11-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2024-03-14>
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2023/05/17 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xecjk/xeCJK.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-xetex.def))
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ctex/ctexhook.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xtemplate/xtemplate.st
y
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xtemplate/xtemplate-20
23-10-10.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec-xetex.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.cfg)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xecjk/xeCJK.cfg)) (./main.aux)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd) [1] (./main.aux)
xdvipdfmx:fatal: Invalid font: -1 (0)

No output PDF file written.
 
)
Error 256 (driver return code) generating output;
file main.pdf may not be valid.
Transcript written on main.log.

I guess this happens because xelatex doesn't support variable fonts yet.
If xelatex supports variable fonts, could someone tell me why my system shows those errors when trying to compile the document?
If xelatex doesn't support variable fonts, I would appreciate if someone could provide a reliable source that states this or some part in the source code from which I could have concluded this.

Additional information
For those that are not aware of the meaning of VF in the filename NotoSansMonoCJKSC-VF, it stands for "variable font" (link to article in Wikipedia).
I found this issue at the lists.fedoraproject.org mailing list which mentions the same issue with compiling documents that use variable fonts with xelatex.
The code block shown below shows the version of xelatex, which I used to compile the two documents shown above.
xelatex --version

XeTeX 3.141592653-2.6-0.999996 (TeX Live 2024)
kpathsea version 6.4.0
Copyright 2024 SIL International, Jonathan Kew and Khaled Hosny.
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the XeTeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the XeTeX source.
Primary author of XeTeX: Jonathan Kew.
Compiled with ICU version 74.2; using 74.2
Compiled with zlib version 1.3.1; using 1.3.1
Compiled with FreeType2 version 2.13.2; using 2.13.2
Compiled with Graphite2 version 1.3.14; using 1.3.14
Compiled with HarfBuzz version 8.3.0; using 8.3.0
Compiled with libpng version 1.6.43; using 1.6.43
Compiled with pplib version v2.2
Compiled with fontconfig version 2.13.0; using 2.13.1


According to the documentation, current fontspec supports Multiple Master fonts on XeTeX, but not Variable, whereas Variable but not Multiple Master are supported on LuaTeX.
fontspec.pdf section 7 page 32:

Currently OpenType variable fonts are only supported in LuaTeX, while
Multiple Master fonts only work with XeTeX.

fontspec 2024/02/13 v2.9a
This is the version of fontspec currently on CTAN (2024-04-27).

Reading through the fontspec documentation, it seems that only LuaLaTeX supports variable fonts; fontspec added support for them very recently, in version 2.9a.
